# Select de datas

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Preciso fazer um select que me traga ocorrências que a data inicial de uma licença seja menor que 3 anos da data de admissão de um funcionário

Segue abaixo trecho do meu código.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    jmh_licenca l
    INNER JOIN
    jmh_servidor s on l.lic_ser_id = s.ser_id
    INNER JOIN
    jmh_doenca d ON l.doe_id = d.doe_id 
WHERE
    l.lic_data_inicial BETWEEN '2012-08-01' AND '2015-08-01' AND
    l.lic_data_inicial **< (3anos)** s.ser_data_admissao AND
    tip_lic_id in ('9', '12');
```

Comment: AND year(l.lic_data_inicial) < 3
só que ***year*** tem que ser referente a data de admissão de cada funcionário.

Comment: Veja esse link ... [Aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749639/how-to-get-the-difference-in-years-from-two-different-dates)

Answer (score 1):

Tenta com o seguinte código:

```
SELECT * FROM jmh_licenca l
INNER JOIN jmh_servidor s on l.lic_ser_id = s.ser_id 
INNER JOIN jmh_doenca d ON l.doe_id = d.doe_id 
WHERE l.lic_data_inicial
BETWEEN '2012-08-01' AND '2015-08-01' 
AND l.lic_data_inicial < s.ser_data_admissao - INTERVAL '3 Year' AND tip_lic_id in ('9', '12');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from
    jmh_licenca l
    inner join
    jmh_servidor s on l.lic_ser_id = s.ser_id
    inner join
    jmh_doenca d on l.doe_id = d.doe_id 
where
    l.lic_data_inicial between '2012-08-01' and '2015-08-01' and
    l.lic_data_inicial::timestamp - s.ser_data_admissao < interval '3 years' and
    tip_lic_id in ('9', '12');
```